# c# iterate through embedded resources and parse folder portion

Tags: c#, foreach, embedded-resource

I am trying to iterate through a folder of bitmaps which are an embedded resource.  I have a dozen or so different folders each containing many files.

I believe that the format is MyNamespace.Folder.MyImage.bmp.

I am trying something like this:

```
foreach (string resourceName in assembly.GetManifestResourceNames())
{    if (resourceName == WantedFolder)  {  do something}   
}
```

I am uncertain how to parse the resourceName string in order to remove the Namspace, MyImage and Extention (bmp) and then only check for the Folder portion of the file...

Comment: Have you thought about simply doing something like a contains match on the `resourceName` with the `WantedFolder`?

Comment: Do you know how to manipulate strings? if yes then is just a matter of removing the namespace and split by dot. If you don't know, then use MSDN and read the string manipulation functions help.